# Word clouds on maps

Tags: maps, word-cloud

Can someone recommend a good way to render word clouds on maps?  I can't seem to find a good example online.  Ideally, I'd like to show a map where a user can click on an area identified by a zip code, and then have a word cloud appear for that area.

Edit:

If this is not the correct forum to ask this question, where would the correct forum be?

Comment: What language are you using? Where are you getting the maps? How can you expect an answer to such a vague question?

Comment: It's vague because I'm just searching for ideas at this point.  I don't care about languages.  As far as getting the maps, I'm open to ideas.  I know of Google Maps, but I also know there exist other products.  I was really hoping the community could point me to some resources.

Comment: I guess I should quote the StackOverflow Help Topic on Questions here: "asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic